# How do I restore the pivot point to the original pivot location?

Tags: transforms

I am trying to animate a character pivoting on his leg to turn around. I've found that I can click at the center of his foot, use Ctrl+Alt+Shift+C and select Origin to 3D cursor, but after doing that and rotating the character, I want to restore the pivot point to where it originally was. The creator of the rig made it so the pivot point it as a local Y=0, but selecting Origin to Center of Mass surface/volume just moves the pivot up to his face.

Is there a way to move the pivot point, work with the new pivot point, and "undo" the pivot translation without actually undoing the work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A characters origin in most cases should always be 0,0, rotate the character from different locations using the 3D cursor as the pivot point instead.

Comment: Wow, looks like I was overcomplicating things. I'm still curious though, is there a way to restore the pivot point back to what it originally was?

Comment: As far as I know there is no pivot point history you can revert back to. You can rotate from any vertex, edge, face, object selected though, or you can snap the 3D Cursor to any selection and then use it to pivot from, even type in the location values for the 3D cursor.

Answer (score 1):

You do not need to change the origin point of the object. Just set the pivot point to 3d cursor (keystroke is dot), set the cursor to desired location, then rotate what you need, and finally, change the pivot point to whatever you want (Ctrl + comma = median point). For rigged characters I often do this: select a toe bone, Shift+S, 4 (cursor to selected), then 7 on the numpad (top ortho view), Dot (pivot point is 3d cursor), select the IK leg control of my rig, R to rotate foot on the toes, then Ctrl+comma to return the pivot point, go back to normal view to fix the foot roll, and continue animating.

Comment: Yes keyboard shortcuts are very sexy, this how you speed up your workflow, cheers Mechanic